# Add option to droplist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a droplist, and I would like to add an All as the first one.

How is that done with asp.net mvc?

I have:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("selCustomerID") %>
```

works great, but I don't have an empty "all-option". I populate it like this:

```
return View("Index", new CustomerAdminEditViewModel { selCustomerID = new SelectList(_cs.GetCustomers(), "CustomerID", "CustomerName") });
```

Comment: <%= Html.DropDownList("selCustomerID", "All") %> worked in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link : http://forums.asp.net/t/1429075.aspx

It is talking about an optional label parameter in the constructor.